# Yii2 adding a property to the application

Tags: properties, configuration, yii2

I would like to add a new property 'business' to the Yii2 application so I can access it like:

```
Yii::$app->business
```

I have tried adding it directly to the config file:

```
'Id' => 'app-frontend',
'name' => 'Application Name',
'business' => 'Business Name',
....
```

Which gives me an 'unknown property exception' for 'buisness'

After some searching I tried:

```
Yii::$app->session->set('app.business','Business Name');
Yii::$app->session->get('app.buisness');
```

But only works when I access it by session

I know how to create it in the params set up, but rather us the app->name. method.

I imagine I need to add the business property in the root model?  But not sure where to drill into it at.

Any help to point me in the right direction please.

Comment: Check if you have the correct name. `app.business` not  `app.buisness`

Comment: The question is if you really need to do that just because of some sort of label. It's usually not the best idea to fight the way the frameworks are designed, so you should have a good reason when you decide to do that. Otherwise you are going to give headaches to anyone who will have to deal with that code in future.

Comment: I do understand what you are saying, It was one of those situations where I came across a need that could have been solved in a few different and possible better ways but when I bumped up against a wall I needed to find a way to open the door.  And typically an answer from this group opens a door with much more possibilities as well.  The option to extend the application may come in useful down the road.

Answer (score 2):

You can extend Application class, add required properties, and use it on bootstrap.

Create class for web:

```
class MyApplication extends \yii\web\Application {

    public $supportname;
}
```

And use it in index.php:

`(new MyApplication($config))->run();`
You need to do the same for \yii\console\Application and yii script.